# Dual values returned after SELECT using PHP and PDO with DB2 over ODBC

Tags: php, odbc, pdo, db2

I am having a weird issue with PDO when I query a DB2 database using ODBC. I am using PHP 5.3.8 compiled using DB2 Express-C V9.7. The result set always returns dual values for each column. Here's the code:

```
$pdo = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER};DATABASE=xxxx; HOSTNAME=x.y.z.a;PORT=xxxxx;CurrentSchema=xxx;", "username", "password");

$sql = 'select * from cust_div where cust_no = '.$params.';';

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->fetchAll();

$stmt->closeCursor();
```

`var_dump($result)` always returns dual values:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(52) {
    ["CUST_NO"]=>
    string(9) "226622249"
    [0]=>
    string(9) "226622249"
    ["DIV_ID"]=>
    string(1) "P"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "P"

    etc.
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is defined behavior for PDO. The array (for each row) returned by `fetch()` or `fetchAll()` contains data indexed by column name and order in the table.

If you don't want the numerically indexed results you can add the `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` constant to your call to fetch:

```
$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); //Just column names and values
//OR
$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

The default value for this first parameter (which PHP.net calls fetch style) is `PDO::FETCH_BOTH` which returns both `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` and `PDO::FETCH_NUM`. More can be found on these return styles on the [fetch() doc page](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php).

For the table below and the query `SELECT * FROM cust`:

```
+--+----+
|id|name|
+--+----+
|0 |John|
+--+----+
|1 |Jill|
+--+----+
```

Calling `$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` would return:

```
array(0=>array(
    'id' => 0,
    'name' => 'John'
), 1=>array(
    'id' => 1,
    'name' => 'Jill'
));
```

While calling `$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);` would return:

```
array(0=>array(
    0 => 0,
    1 => 'John'
), 1=>array(
    0 => 1,
    1 => 'Jill'
));
```

The default (`PDO::FETCH_BOTH`), which is what you've encountered, returns a combination of both of them. Since it is the default, it is used when no style is passed:

```
$stmt->fetch();
```

Or when it is explicitly provided:

$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);

Comment: Please elaborate. You're saying that PDO returns the key=>value, and the value?

Comment: @eriben Depending on the flag it can return: `column_name => value`, `column_number => value` or a combination of the two (see my edits).

Answer (score 0):

You can define the "fetch style" by passing in an argument to `fetchall()`.

```
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

See here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php